# Unable to use InsertAfter for XmlDocument in c#

Tags: c#, xml, insertafter

Hi below are the XML files which is master XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
 <Verify>
  <ver>
     <ECU>
      <values>
      </values>
     </ECU>
  </ver>
 </Verify>
```

I have multiple files which are of same structure as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
 <Verify>
  <ver>
     <ECU>
      <values>
      </values>
     </ECU>
  </ver>
 </Verify>
```

I want my output as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
 <Verify>
  <ver>
     <ECU>
      <values>
      </values>
     </ECU>

     <ECU>
      <values>
      </values>
     </ECU>

     <ECU>
      <values>
      </values>
     </ECU>
  </ver>
 </Verify>
```

I am using below code to read first one as master xml
and other files from xmls folder. I want to add ECU node from these files under ECU node of master file.

```
XmlDocument xmlMaster = new XmlDocument();
        xmlMaster.Load(@"C:\MasterXMLFile.xml");
        XmlElement masterRoot = xmlMaster.DocumentElement;
        XmlNode masterParent = masterRoot.LastChild.LastChild;
        var downloadfolder = @"C:\AllXMLs\xmls\";
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(downloadfolder);
        foreach (var xx in files)
        {
            XmlNode masterNode = masterRoot.LastChild.LastChild;
            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            xdoc.Load(xx);
            XmlElement root = xdoc.DocumentElement;
            XmlElement tempNode = (XmlElement)root.LastChild.LastChild;
            masterRoot.InsertAfter(tempNode, masterRoot.SelectSingleNode("//ECU").ParentNode);
        }
        xmlMaster.Save(@"C:\mergeg.xml");
```

I am getting error at InsertAfter statement as Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Please suggest me any solution.

Comment: Don't expect `LastChild` to select an element node, it can be a text node. So simply select the element you want to copy with XPath and `SelectSingleNode`. And then make sure you use `ImportNode` if you want to copy a node from one document to a different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `tempNode` is from `xdoc` document context. You should import it to `xmlMaster` document context:

```
XmlNode importedECU = xmlMaster.ImportNode(tempNode, true);
```

Also instead of `InsertAfter` it's better to use `AppendChild` and append new ECU nodes as children of master `ver` element:

```
var masterVer = masterRoot.SelectSingleNode("//ver");

foreach(var file in files)
{
   var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
   xdoc.Load(file);
   var tempNode = xdoc.DocumentElement.LastChild.LastChild;
   var importedECU = xmlMaster.ImportNode(tempNode, true); 
   masterVer.AppendChild(importedECU);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your InsertAfter should be on the parentNode of the node you want to insert after, so the parent of tempNode.